# IE Web Driver runs 3-5 times slower running on TeamCity Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, teamcity, windows-server-2012

I am running a suite of UI tests using Team City on Windows Server 2012.  The tests in consideration run on my local machine in 60-90 seconds.  On the nightly build through Team City CI server, they run in 3.5-5.5 minutes. They are written in C# and run in IEDriverServer.exe 32-bit version 2.37.0. My question, is there any reason for the inconsistency and any steps I can take to debug the slowness on Windows Server 2012?

The question isn't about the performance between IE and chrome, which I know is quite different, but rather the difference between the performance of IE on my local machine and the server. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850211/why-is-selenium-internetexplorerdriver-webdriver-very-slow-in-debug-mode-visual) may be helpful. (PS: tests run in 12-20 seconds in chrome and IE, there are many of screenshots.)

Comment: I finally got tests running manually with Nunit GUI and they were running at a normal speed. There must be something affecting them via TC i'm missing.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

One reason i can think of is system resource utilization when the tests are running. That is how many processes are running and how much of CPU/RAM are they consuming. I implemented a Jenkins CI setup and saw that the resource utilization on the test machine was very high and the tests were running very slow. May not be a similar situation for you, but wanted to share my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but with chromedriver. The tests ran up to 10 times slower via TeamCity compared to locally. I narrowed it down to setting DNS refresh timeout to 0.

```
ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;
```

Once I increased this to a few seconds the tests took the same time on TeamCity vs locally.